# Try exception alternative for protect not crash application

Tags: string, go, runtime-error

I have a Go application for scrape URLs. The problem is it sometimes crashes and returns this error:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.dom6(0x187d4140, 0x8, 0x187d4179, 0x5, 0x187c0800, 0x6, 0x13, 0x83007cb)
        /root/sswork.go:326 +0x6b
main.sub(0x187d4140, 0x8, 0x84464e0, 0x6, 0x6, 0x187d4140, 0x8, 0x187d4179, 0x5, 0x187c0800, ...)
        /root/sswork.go:298 +0xb3
main.main()
        /root/sswork.go:615 +0xccb
```

on line 298 is this function :

```
294: // try our list of substitutions, if one works return it
295: func sub(str string, xs []subs, u string, p string, h string) string {
296:    for _, x := range xs {
297:        if strings.Contains(str, x.pattern) {
298:            return strings.Replace(str, x.pattern, x.fn(u, p, h), 1)
299:        }
300:    }
301:    return str
302:}
```

How can I solve my problem so it doesn't crash the application any more?

```
324: // the first 6 characters of the above
325: func dom6(u string, p string, d string) string {
326:    return domfull(u, p, d)[0:6]
327: }
```

Comment: The error is at line 326, not 298. And to avoid such panics, perform manual index check before attempting to index or slice a slice or array.

Comment: // the first 6 characters of the above
func dom6(u string, p string, d string) string {
 return domfull(u, p, d)[0:6]
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is at line 326, not 298. And to avoid such panics, perform manual index check before attempting to index or slice a slice, array or string.

You indicated that the code at line 298 is:

```
// the first 6 characters of the above
func dom6(u string, p string, d string) string {
    return domfull(u, p, d)[0:6]
}
```

Check the length of the `string` returned by `domfull()` before attempting to slice it, e.g.:

```
func dom6(u string, p string, d string) string {
    df := domfull(u, p, d)
    if len(df) < 6 {
        return df
    }
    return df[:6]
}
```

Comment: after change function dom6, return this error : ./sswork.go:621: assignment count mismatch: 2 = 1
./sswork.go:625: assignment count mismatch: 2 = 1

Comment: @LucianBlaga Line 625 is entirely elsewhere, I do not know what that is. Also I only suggested to change the body of the function (but not its signature), I don't see how that could cause the error you mentioned.